# Android math operator

Tags: android

I need calculate a thing. but my formula sentence has occur some problem.

```
 TextView ticketP = (TextView)findViewById (R.id.ticketQ);

  ticketP.setText(oneSession.getTicketOder());

String Ctotal = "";

Ctotal = jsonObject.optString("price");




String OneTotal = oneSession.getTicketOder() * Ctotal; // this part has occur the problem which is the operator *  .
```

Comment: do you want to multiply a string for something else? I doubt the string multiplication is defined, I suspect you need to do Integer.parseInt first

Comment: ya..thank you...problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to convert the Strings to numeric type before performing any multiplication.  Depending on the type of numeric value you are using take a look [Double.parseDouble(String string)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) or [Integer.parseInt(String string)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thank you... can u help me one more problem ?

total_One = (TextView)findViewById (R.id.totalOder); 
 double FTotal = perT * Tprice; 
   total_One.setText(FTotal);

how come cannot use the setText to display?

Comment: total_One.setText(String.valueOf(FTotal));

Answer (score 0):

```
int oneTotal = Integer.valueOf(oneSession.getTicketOder()) * Integer.valueOf(Ctotal);
```

to convert it again to String use

`String.valueOf(oneTotal)`

Comment: Integer.valueOf() is actually more than you need right here. Integer.valueOf() returns an object of type Integer, where as the parse methods return the native type, not the wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your going to have to use the parsing methods in order to convert the string to a native numerical type. You also need to be care about a few things with your code.

json.optString() can return null. opt = optional.
I would suggest using json.getInt() or json.getDouble() this will not only give you the correct type, but also throw an exception if the values aren't correct.

Secondly your going to have to convert your numerical answer back to a string if you want to display it. But this is easy enough with a .toString() or + "" if you are lazy.

Comment: oh i see..just now i was wondering the optString with getString..now i have some idea already...Thank you...